# can any one suggest how to design custom datetimepicker in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

Need help

Please give me the suggestion how to create custom datepicker like below screen short
http://prntscr.com/ext4oo

Heres what my current one looks like.
http://prntscr.com/ezgcol

Comment: What is so great about the first one, compared to the second? You need it to include *times*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you are showing is from the company Telerik. They make custom UI for different frameworks. 
But to answer your question. You will have to make a custom usercontrol.
With dynamic clickable labels/links for your days, months and years.
You could inherit from the `DateTimePicker` Class and uses different methods to do what you want to do.

In my opinion it's really a lot of work to make it looks "nicer". I hope this answers your question.

Comment: All correct, except that inheriting from `DateTimePicker` won't get you very far. It wasn't designed to be inherited from, and doesn't support any kind of "custom drawing" of its UI. You'll basically have to write the *entire control* from scratch. I'd agree that this is definitely not worth it. It doesn't even look that much nicer. (Especially not if you were using a different Windows theme—something other than "Classic"—which the built-in control would pick up automatically.)